# Valence GettingStartedSample won't run

Tags: desire2learn, valence

This is a Valence newbie question but I've observed the behaviour of the GettingStarted sample at http://samples.valence.desire2learn.com/samples/GettingStartedSample/ - then downloaded the JavaScript client library SDK files for this sample and tried running it from a development server.  Nothing happened at all but I noted two things.

First was that I had to make sure the two js includes from the lib folder were moved in to position in accordance with these two includes on the test page...

```
 <script src="lib/valence.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/sha.js"></script>
```

Second problem is these three includes in the same test page...

```
<script src="sample.js"></script>
<script src="server.js"></script>
<script src = "jquery.jsonp-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

They weren't included at all in the javascript zip that I downloaded. The absence of these includes is my number one suspect for the sample not working at all.

This is my first go at using the API so I might be missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Some files were missing in the published release. Please get the [latest release](https://github.com/Desire2Learn-Valence/valence-sdk-javascript/releases/tag/1.0.1) from the GitHub.

To deploy, copy the entire contents to your web server and visit `http://{your server}/{path you copied it to}/valence-sdk-javascript/sample/GettingStartedSample/`.